# How to implement aggregation on Apollo GraphQL server?

Tags: knex.js, apollo-server

I am using [Apollo GraphQL server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/) + [SQLDatasource](https://github.com/cvburgess/SQLDataSource) (with [knex](http://knexjs.org/)) to fetch data from a database, but I don't know how to return the aggregated data when using SQL functions like **COUNT**, **AVG**, **MAX**. That's because normally GraphQL uses a static schema to describe the shape of the data returned by the graph, for instance:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type User {
        Id: ID
        Birth: Date
        Name: String
    }
`;
```

For instance, how could I fetch the result of the following query in GraphQL, having into account that the aggregation functions could be dynamic?

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_users, MAX(Id) AS max_id, Id, Birth, Name FROM User;
```

Comment: Check this https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Comment: Thanks felixmosh but I was looking for a solution on Apollo GraphQL  + knex.